Copying directory into sub directories in linux
I have a directory MAIN with approximately 1200 files ending with .bam. I want to copy these files from MAIN to "/path/to/output/folder" but in sub directories having 50 .bam files each. So basically i want to split the files of the MAIN into subdirectories having 50 files each. Sub directories will not be in MAIN folder.
I have found a solution on this Platform but not sure how to modify it by adding the output path and making it for copying the files not moving.
i=0; 

for f in *; 
do 
    d=dir_$(printf %03d $((i/50+1))); 
    mkdir -p $d; 
    mv "$f" $d; 
    let i++; 
done


For a simple fix, you can just replace mv with cp to switch from moving to copying, then prefix $d with the output prefix (e.g. "/path/to/$d").
That said, there are some caveats regarding that solution.
I'm assuming you're probably working with "nice" file and directory names, but since that's not always a safe assumption, I recommend looking at Why is looping over find's output bad practice? for safe ways to loop over file names.
Here's one solution that should properly handle arbitrary file names:
ORIGIN_DIR="/path/to/origin"
DESTINATION_PARENT_DIR="/path/to/destination"
SHARD_SIZE=50
FIND_BY_NAME="*.bam"

readarray -d '' -t ORIGIN_FILES < <(
  find "$ORIGIN_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$FIND_BY_NAME" -print0
)

for index in "${!ORIGIN_FILES[@]}"; do
  shard_suffix="$(printf %03d $(($index / $SHARD_SIZE + 1)))"
  destination_dir="$DESTINATION_PARENT_DIR/part_$shard_suffix"
  mkdir -p "$destination_dir"
  cp "${ORIGIN_FILES[$index]}" "$destination_dir/"
done

If you want to recursively search all paths under the origin directory instead of just handling its direct children, you can remove the -maxdepth 1 argument.

With the bash shell, you could potentially do something like this:

Place all relevant filenames in an array.
While there are at least 50 names in the array:

Copy the first 50 filenames to their destination directory.
Remove those names from the array.


Copy the remaining files to their destination.

destdir=/path/to/output/folder

names=( MAIN/*.bam )

n=1
while [[ ${#names[@]} -gt 50 ]]; do
    subdir=$destdir/sub-$n
    mkdir -p "$subdir" || exit

    cp "${names[@]:0:50}" "$subdir"

    names=( ${names[@]:50} )  # Remove first 50 names from list.
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
done

if [[ ${#names[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    # Copy the remaining (less than 50 names) to their destination.
    subdir=$destdir/sub-$n
    mkdir -p "$subdir" || exit
    cp "${names[@]}" "$subdir"
fi

Using the list of positional parameters instead of a named array (and change the syntax to plain POSIX shell syntax):
destdir=/path/to/output/folder

set -- MAIN/*.bam

n=1
while [ "$#" -gt 50 ]; do
    subdir=$destdir/sub-$n
    mkdir -p "$subdir" || exit

    # Copy the 50 first files in the list to their destination.
    k=50
    while [ "$k" -gt 0 ]; do
        cp "$1" "$subdir"
        shift
        k=$(( k - 1 ))
    done

    n=$(( n + 1 ))
done

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    # Copy the remaining (less than 50 names) to their destination.
    subdir=$destdir/sub-$n
    mkdir -p "$subdir" || exit
    cp "$@" "$subdir"
fi


If you need just roughly 50 files in each directory, you could calculate how many directories it would take to store your files and then randomly distribute the files across those directories.
This requires a shell that knows about the special RANDOM variable:
destdir=~/tmp

set -- MAIN/*.bam
ndirs=$(( $# / 50 ))

for name do
        subdir=$destdir/sub-$(( RANDOM % ndirs ))
        mkdir -p "$subdir" || exit

        cp "$name" "$subdir"
done

